# Task Queue Premium Call Count

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

As we scale up our service and add backends that use the pull queue REST API, we find that we are hitting the 100k/day limit.  The documentation is not clear on whether or not this is billable.  Is it possible to exceed this limit with billing enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Enable billing and the limit increases to 1,000,000,000
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Task_Queue

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your info is outdated - this is not a limit that is listed in the current version of the quotas for pull queues:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Pull_Queues